# Problems with jdbc loadbalance

Tags: java, mysql, load-balancing, apache-commons-dbcp, jdbc-pool

We are using jdbc load balancing like "jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://..." and apache DBCP with maxidle 300 connections.. 
And when after some actions I look at processes in Mysql via "SHOW PROCESSLIST" is show me very many connection. In normal behaviour it would be 3-4 connections everytime. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found bug related to this issue: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35660. (we are using connector 5.0.8). This bug has been fixed in the later version.